# Killing a process in Batch and reporting on success

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, errorlevel

i have the following batch file, which terminates the iTunes program so, that if i connect my iPod, it's not going to sync it. (I know you can set this up in iTunes.)

```
@echo off
:kill
cls
taskkill /F /IM itunes.exe >nul
if %errorlevel%==1 {
echo iTunes not found.
} else {
echo iTunes is killed.
}
goto kill
```

However, the `>nul` does not respond to the command; so it just gives the default command text. So yeah, what i want to do:

If iTunes is not found, as given by the command, it should display

> iTunes not found

If it is found and terminated,

> iTunes is killed

Help? the errorlevel's don't work, this seem to be the fault of the `nul` not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Works for me at least:

```
> taskkill /f /im powershell.exe && echo worked || echo not worked
SUCCESS: The process "powershell.exe" with PID 3228 has been terminated.
worked

> taskkill /f /im powershell.exe && echo worked || echo not worked
ERROR: The process "powershell.exe" not found.
not worked
```

So `taskkill` *is* returning a proper exit code. The redirect of its output has nothing to do with this. But the error level for failure is 128. You really should use the proper idiom for checking for errors.

Also it seems that `taskkill` is printing to `stderr` so you see its output still, when just redirecting `stdout`. You may consider rewriting above code to:

```
taskkill /F /IM itunes.exe >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (echo iTunes not found.) else (echo iTunes is killed.)
```

The `2>&1` redirects the standard error output into the vast nothingness. `if errorlevel 1` checks for `errorlevel` being *at least 1* which should work at this point:

> **ERRORLEVEL number** Specifies a true condition if the last program run returned an exit code equal to or greater than the number specified. —`help if`

Generally checking `errorlevel` with `if %errorlevel%==` is a quite bad idea, unless you're comparing to 0. The semantics for exit codes are that `anything` non-zero signals failure. Your assumption here just was that `taskkill` would return `1` on failure.

Ans may I kindly ask why you are doing this in an endless loop? `taskkill` already kills *all* instances of `itunes.exe`. And you're running in a tight loop without any delays so your batch files probably consumes one CPU core while it's running.

**ETA:** Overlooked your edit: Why on earth curly braces? Blocks in batch files are delimieted by round parentheses.

Comment: `why on eart curly braces`, well, i use them as long as i worked with them. I don't know; i just like it. It looks nicer i guess.

Comment: Well, if you're using them in batch files, then expect things going wrong. If you write code in a language you have to use the language's grammar, regardless what looks nicer or not. Curly braces don't work as block delimiters in batch.

Comment: i thought they did. At least they worked for the codes i used. I work with batch for over 1 year now, and have developed with curly braces, over and over, and it works fine. My customers (aka youtubers ;)) say it works fine for them.

Comment: oh, and about the endless loop: i edited the thing so that at `else` it says: `else(goto :killed)`. In `:killed`, we have an additional 2 times taskkill, just to be sure, and after that, it echo a text, and tells the user it should press any key to `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative solution, in vbscript, save below code as mykill.vbs

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
strProcess = objArgs(0)
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcesses = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name ='" & strProcess & "'")

If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo strProcess & " is not running."
Else
    Wscript.Echo strProcess & " is running."
    'Kill the process
    For Each objProcess in colProcesses
        r=objProcess.Terminate()
        WScript.Echo "r is " & r
        If r = 0 Then
            WScript.Echo strProcess & " killed"
        End If
    Next        
End If
```

on the command line

```
c:\test> cscript //nologo mykill.vbs "itunes.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use PowerShell?

```
try
{
    Stop-Process -Name itunes -ErrorAction Stop
    "iTunes is killed"
}
catch
{
    "iTunes not found"
}
```