# Killing a process with taskkill /F returning code 0

Tags: windows, process, batch-file, return-code, taskkill

I need to kill a windows process (java.exe). I'm currently using:

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM java.exe
```

I need to use the /F option since is a critical process,but in this way I get a return code 1 instead I need a return code 0 (returned when I don't use /F for killing other not critical processes)

how could I fix this problem?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with :

```
TASKKILL /F /IM "notepad.exe"
```

You can know more [here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/database-solutions/kill-a-process-in-windows-bat-19875). Visit [this blog](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/a-batch-file-to-kill-a-process/12884.html) too.

Comment: The link details for "here" and "this blog" are dead links. So we get an answer that looks the same as the question, with no explanation for why it's the correct answer or what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use PowerShell?

```
Stop-Process -Name java.exe
```

From the old command prompt:

```
powershell -Command "Stop-Process -Name java.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using following command on Windows Server 2008R2

```
Taskkill /IM B2B_Crawler_V2.exe /F
```

Refer [Taskkill](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true)  and [Killing a process in Batch and reporting on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896262/killing-a-process-in-batch-and-reporting-on-success)

Answer (score 0):

Execute this in CMD

Get the list of open processes

```
netstat -a -o -n
```

And then kill the process on that port with the following command

```
taskkill /F /PID <pid>
```