# Webpack dev server - the process with PID 13960 could not be terminated

Tags: windows, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

my webback dev server doesn't work properly in windows 7, cygwin.

It always work for on the first time but when i terminate the process and re-run it will get the error of the port already in use.

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:9000
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hkooa1jz/) is the configuration content of my webpack dev server.

```
var config = {
   entry: './main.js',

   output: {
      path:'./',
      filename: 'index.js',
   },

   devServer: {
     historyApiFallback: true,
     contentBase: './',
     inline: true,
     port : 9000
   },

   module: {
      loaders: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',

            query: {
               presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}

module.exports = config;
```

I have check the Active connection and found it in use, but i can't kill it.

```
$ netstat -a -n -o'
TCP    127.0.0.1:9000         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       13960

$ taskkill /PID 13960 
ERROR: The process with PID 13960 could not be terminated.  
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
```

Thanks.

Comment: probably a duplicate question, refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151314/killing-a-process-with-taskkill-f-returning-code-0

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reference link. Is there any other ways to auto terminate webpack dev process when i hit ctrl+c ?