# Batch file: Check for program, restart, or do nothing

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, application-restart, tasklist, taskkill

I'm struggling a bit with this. The idea of the script should be:

If program 1 is running
Close it then open it
If not running
Do nothing

This will be used on XP and win7 machines

Here's what I have, but I have no idea how to incorporate the if statements or even if what I have is remotely correct:

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq KDS.exe" taskkill /f /im "KDS.exe"  start "" "C:\Path\KDS.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the `taskkill` first, and check its return value to determine whether it succeeded or not.  If it did, then restart the process.

```
taskkill /f /im "kds.exe" && (
    start "" "C:\Path\KDS.exe"
)
```

Source of inspiration:  [Killing a process in Batch and reporting on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896262/killing-a-process-in-batch-and-reporting-on-success)

Comment: I tried exactly that on a computer where the process wasn't running, and it started it. The idea would be to check if it's running, if it is to restart it. If it's not running, don't try and start the program.

Comment: Hrmph.  Sure enough.  I've added the `/f` flag and used `/im` instead of `/fi`, and now it returns the error codes I was expecting.